# How to add arrows below the original axis in plotly 2D scatter plot

Tags: plot, plotly

Creating 2D scatter plot by plotly can be done following the example from:

https://plot.ly/python/line-and-scatter/

However, is there any easy way to add arrows below the x axis?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Plotly's [annotations](https://plot.ly/python/text-and-annotations/) without text.

[image]

```
import plotly
import numpy as np

plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
N = 1000

data = [plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(x=np.random.randn(N),
                                  y=np.random.randn(N),
                                  mode = 'markers'
                                 )
       ]

xstart = -2
xmax = 3.5
xmin = -3.5
padding = 0.05
ypos = -0.1

layout = plotly.graph_objs.Layout(
    xaxis=dict(range=[xmin, xmax]),
    showlegend=False,
    annotations=[
        dict(
            x=xmin,
            y=ypos,
            ax=xstart + padding,
            ay=ypos,
            xref='x',
            axref='x',
            yref='paper',
            ayref='paper',
            showarrow=True,
            arrowhead=2,
            arrowsize=1,
            arrowwidth=3,
            arrowcolor='#0000ff',
        ),
        dict(
            x=xmax,
            y=ypos,
            ax=xstart - padding,
            ay=ypos,
            xref='x',
            axref='x',
            yref='paper',
            ayref='paper',
            showarrow=True,
            arrowhead=2,
            arrowsize=1,
            arrowwidth=3,
            arrowcolor='#ff0000',
        )
    ])

plotly.offline.iplot(plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=data, 
                                              layout=layout))
```

Comment: Do you know how to do the annotation on 3D? I have no problem to reproduce your result on 2D, but when I try to apply on 3D graph, the annotation does not follow the graph (or node) after rotation.

Comment: @user2149631: I think scatter3d behave differently with annotations. See: https://plot.ly/javascript/text-and-annotations/#3d-annotations

Comment: Thanks, Maximilian! Is it possible to put the arrow outside of the plotting region for 3D? I tried something like: p = layout(p,
  scene = list(
    annotations = list(list(
      x = 0.3,
      y = -0.1,
      z = -0.1,
      text = "12345",
      textangle= 0,
      ax = 0,
      ay = -75,
      xref='x',
      axref='x',
      yref = 'paper',
      ayref = 'paper',
      zref = 'paper',
      arrowcolor= "black",
      arrowsize= 3,
      arrowwidth= 1,
      arrowhead= 1
    ))
  )
). But it doesn't work.

Comment: My RStudio just crashes when I add the `layout`. Time for a new question?

Comment: Yeah, I save the plot to a html file and then open it in the browser. I will open a new question.

Comment: Please check the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45623139/how-to-add-arrow-below-the-y-axis-in-plotly-3d-scatter-plot